# Passing an array in a specific location in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of bytes, if I just want X number of bytes in a specific location of that array, I am wondering if this is valid.

Also my code is crashing here, the following piece of code was provided to me.. but it crash on my system and don't know why.

rawDataPtr is my array of bytes, as you can guess the value that i am interested on starts on positon 4.

```
float TempFloat = COMMON_ConvertByteArrayToFloat(&rawDataPtr[3]);
```

Now the function.

```
union {
    uint8_t tmpArray[4];
    float tmpFloat;
}value;

float COMMON_ConvertByteArrayToFloat(uint8_t *data) {

    value.tmpArray[0] = data[3];
    value.tmpArray[1] = data[2];
    value.tmpArray[2] = data[1];
    value.tmpArray[3] = data[0];

    return value.tmpFloat;
}
```

Comment: What is `rawDataPtr` (and what is its size) and where exactly your program crash?

Comment: rawDataPtr is a message recieved using UART, I just collect the bytes and save them, the size can vary depending on the msg, it crashes exactly when I call COMMON_ConvertByteArrayToFloat it does not go in it.

Comment: If it's crashing when you do the call, the problem is in the caller, not in the function. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an array of bytes, if I just want X number of bytes in a specific location of that array, I am wondering if this is valid.

Supposing that "array" `rawDataPtr` has at least four elements, `&rawDataPtr[3]` is a valid pointer to the fourth.  If the element type is different from `uint8_t` then you technically ought to cast to `uint8_t *` when you pass it to your function:

```
float TempFloat = COMMON_ConvertByteArrayToFloat((uint8_t *) &rawDataPtr[3]);
```

... but in practice that is unlikely to make any difference.

Your function is fine in itself.  In particular,

1. there is no problem accessing `data[0]` ... `data[3]` as you do, *provided that* `data` is a valid pointer, and that referencing `data[3]` does not constitute an attempt to read outside the bounds of the object (in)to which `data` points.  In the usage you present, that corresponds to `rawDataPtr` being an array of at least 7 bytes.
2. it is permissible to write to one element of a union and subsequently read from another, though there are some caveats.  In particular, your code assumes that `float`s are four bytes in size; if they are longer on your system then your code has unspecified behavior.

Additional notes:

- I assume it is intentional that you reverse the byte order from your array to form the value of your `float`.  Whether that is appropriate is a function of your particular data.
- If you are going to perform the bytes -> float conversion via a union, then it is advisable to use a union object that is local to the function.  You presently appear to be using a file-scoped instance instead.
- Your function is entirely capable of producing a trap representation in `value.tmpFloat`, and then attempting to read and return that value.  If it does so then the resulting behavior is undefined.

Overall, if the function is crashing your program then it is because you are feeding it bad data.  In that case, it is likely that either the caller's `rawDataPtr` is not a valid pointer (and note that it's name suggests that it is a *pointer* not an array), or it points to fewer than four bytes before the end of an object, or the bytes to which it points form a trap representation when converted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer John, I made another post in which I provide more details, if you will be so kind to take a look I would really appreciated. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315607/c-cannot-access-memory-at-location