# C - Cannot access memory at address

Tags: c, gdb, embedded, c11

When debugging GDB  tells me the following error:

```
0x800c99ed00000001 < error: Cannot access memory at address 0x800c99ed00000001>
```

The error is produced if I put a breakpoint when I call ConvertByteArrayToFloat while debugging .

But the program exits without a problem and gives me an Ok result ?

My main file:

```
#include "Local.h"

int main(void) {

    if(HandleReceivedMessages() == OP_COMPLETED){
        printf("Main Completed \n" );
    } else {
        printf("Main Failed \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Local.h

```
#ifndef LOCAL_H_
#define LOCAL_H_

#include "Common.h"

T_OP_STATUS HandleReceivedMessages(void);

#endif
```

Local.c

```
#include "Handler.h"
#include "Local.h"

uint8_t message[] = {0x86, 0x9a, 0xa0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x07, 0x00, 0x10, 0x4a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe1};

uint8_t length = 16;

T_OP_STATUS HandleReceivedMessages(void) {

    if(HandleResponseMessage(message, length) == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Completed from Local \n");
        return OP_COMPLETED;
    } else {
        printf("Failed from Local \n");
        return OP_FAILED;
    }

}
```

Handler.h

```
#ifndef HANDLER_H_
#define HANDLER_H_

#include "Common.h"

T_MESSAGE_STATUS HandleResponseMessage(uint8_t *requestData, uint8_t msgLength);


#endif /* HANDLER_H_ */
```

Handler.c

```
#include "Handler.h"
#include <string.h>

static uint8_t rawRequestData[BUFFER_WIRED_SIZE];

static float TempFloat = 0;


T_MESSAGE_STATUS HandleCmd(uint16_t cmdNumber, uint8_t rawDataLength,
                    uint8_t *rawDataPtr) {

    switch (cmdNumber) {
        case 1:
            TempFloat = ConvertByteArrayToFloat(&rawDataPtr[3]);
            printf("The value of the float is : %f \n", TempFloat);
            return STATUS_SUCCESS;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
}


T_MESSAGE_STATUS HandleResponseMessage(uint8_t *message,
                                uint8_t msgLength) {

    uint8_t cmdNumber, dataLength, startOfData;


    // Check the delimiter.
    if (message[0] & INDICATOR_UNIQUE_ADDRESS) {

        cmdNumber = message[6];
        dataLength = message[7];
        startOfData = 8;

    } else {

        cmdNumber = message[2];
        dataLength = message[3];
        startOfData = 4;
    }

    // we copy only the real data from the command response
    memcpy(&rawRequestData, message + startOfData, dataLength);

    return HandleCmd(cmdNumber, dataLength, rawRequestData);

}
```

Common.h

```
#ifndef COMMON_H_
#define COMMON_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_WIRED_SIZE               128
#define INDICATOR_UNIQUE_ADDRESS        0x80


typedef enum {

    OP_FAILED,
    OP_COMPLETED,

}T_OP_STATUS;

typedef enum
{
    STATUS_SUCCESS,
    STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED,

} T_MESSAGE_STATUS;

float ConvertByteArrayToFloat(uint8_t *data);


#endif /* COMMON_H_ */
```

Common.c

```
#include "Common.h"

float ConvertByteArrayToFloat(uint8_t *data) {

    union {
        uint8_t tmpArray[4];
        float tmpFloat;
   } value;

    value.tmpArray[0] = data[3];
    value.tmpArray[1] = data[2];
    value.tmpArray[2] = data[1];
    value.tmpArray[3] = data[0];

    return value.tmpFloat;
}
```

This is the min version, (it does a lot of things like checking the format of the message, CRC, etc..)but goes from start to finish thru all those files.

I am working on an embedded platform and when debugging in my microcontroller and calling the function ConvertByteArrayToFloat, my program jumps to some other part of my code and then it crashes the microcontroller.

I try to recreate the error in my computer without the microcontroller and I found the error at the top.

Comment: What is your microcontroller? Is it big-endian or little-endian? You need/have a func that is the reverse of `ConvertByteArrayToFloat` (e.g. `ConvertFloatToByteArray`), which is not shown, to produce the messages that `ConvertByteArrayToFloat` decodes. You may be hardwiring for the wrong endianness and the convert function blows up when the float is returned. That is, hardwired for [say] x86, so it works there, but controller may be big-endian [or vice-versa]

Comment: The micro is Little endian, but the thing is that in my micro it does not hit the breakpoint inside ConvertByteArrayToFloat, when it reaches that statement it jumps to some other unrelated part of the code and then it just crashes and goes into HardFault. 

Yes there is also a ConvertFloatToByteArray, but it is not being use for the moment, since I am just trying to read values and not write them.

Comment: Sounds like UB caused by earlier UB. I saw the `+3` that unwind did [but figured you'd already checked that]. Could there be another place that overruns a buffer (i.e. do some desk checking) earlier that causes this later problem? Stack overflow due to unintended recursion? On the uC, could interrupt vectors [which bkpt needs] get corrupted? Try a call to the convert func during early init to prove it works at least once. Then, pepper artificial calls to it thoughout (ie. make it the canary in the coal mine). Can you _step_ the code (vs. bkpt)?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the program, and to check, I built it on Linux and ran it under valgrind.  It ran successfully with no issues detected.  Can you actually reproduce the issue in your environment with the code presented here?  In that case GDB's backtrace should tell you pretty exactly where the error occurs -- what does it say?

Comment: Is there a reason why in one place you copy part of the data to a separate buffer, but in another you just pass a pointer to the start of the data in which you're interested?  Copying the data seems wasteful, at least for the cut-down version of the program you've presented.

Comment: When weird stuff like "jumping to another part of my code" is happening then check for a stack overflow.

Comment: It is the debugger rather than your program that is attempting to access the address.   Check that you do not have an invalid object or address in the automatic display list for example.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
TempFloat = ConvertByteArrayToFloat(&rawDataPtr[3]);
```

(where `rawDataPtr` is a `uint8_t *` argument) looks very suspicious. You're passing a pointer to the fourth byte at `rawDataPtr` (same as `rawDataPtr + 3`) to the conversion function, which will then read four bytes starting at that location.

This looks like some kind of confusion after consuming the initial bytes of the message.

Comment: That rawDataPtr is the data send in the message, from that location (3) I know, that there is a 4 byte float inside my data array (rawDataPrt) that is my value in this particular case that I want to extract.

If you see in HandleResponseMessage I just copy a specific part of the message using memcpy that is my data that i then feed to HandleCmd.

Comment: @IzonFreak No, I don't see that. I see how you `memcpy()` from byte 4 in the source into the `rawData`, but then you skip *another* four in the line I quoted, at least that's my understanding right now.

Comment: @IzonFreak I'm afraid I must agree with unwind. So, from the absolute _raw_ buffer start, is the float at offset 4 or 8? That is, which is the header size that needs to be skipped over? If the header is 4, then the code should be `&rawDataPtr[0]`. If it should be `&rawDataPtr[3]`, _after_ the prestrip of 4/8 in `HandleResponseMessage`, what's in `0-3`? Maybe, the easy way is to try it with index 0 and see if UB goes away. Or, work backwards. Put the bkpt on `HandleCmd` or `HandleReponseMessage`

Comment: Whether he's accessing the data he intends to access or not, he's not going outside the bounds of the data he should be able to access.